# Datatable -filter records with linq based on some internal index

Tags: linq

I have a datatable with plenty of records. And i have a range like **lowerRange = 10** and **upperRange = 200**. ***I want the pull the records starting at row 10 till row 200.***

Now **i don't want to add any new index based column** into the datatable. Is there any way with the help of linq, i can pull the set of rows based on some internal datatable index? I guess, the datatable must be maintaining some row index implicitly.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *can* use:

```
var records = table.AsEnumerable().Skip(10).Take(191);
```

That will use the "natural" order of the DataTable. You'll need to make sure that the DataTable is being populated in a useful order though.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In my case, it will be var records = table.AsEnumerable().Skip(9).Take(200);

Comment: @Karan: Are you thinking of rows starting at 1 then? In which case yes, you'd Skip(9)... but then you'd *finish* at row 209 if you take 200 records. The Take isn't an indexed upper bound - it's a limit on the *size* of the returned sequence.

Comment: DataTable dtInvitees = ds.Tables[0];
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = dtInvitees.AsEnumerable().Skip(10).Take(191);  How can i get the datatable again after the linq action? Plz help.

Comment: @Karan: Oh, you mean you want to actually *change* the DataTable? That's not the kind of thing you do in LINQ, which is just about *querying*. You may be able to build a new DataTable based on the sequence, but if you just want to modify the original one, you probably shouldn't be using LINQ to do so.

Comment: so i should convert the records back into new datatable or dataview.

Comment: There is one error i am getting at the last step. I am not sure whay we are getting error at the datatable addition :-         DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
IEnumerable<DataRow> q1 = dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(5).Take(10);
dsInvitee = new DataSet();
DataTable dt2 = q1.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
dsInvitee.Tables.Add(dt2);
dsInvitee.Tables.Add(ds.Tables[1].Copy());

Comment: @Karan: It's hard to tell without knowing what the error is... but I'm not sure why you're creating a new dataset here. What are you trying to achieve, exactly? (It may be worth asking this in a different question, as it's somewhat separate from the Skip/Take part, and people with more DataTable experience may be able to help you.)

Comment: i am trying to create a new dataset and then add datatables to it. But with linq, i am getting the exception of duplicateNameException with datatables. Exception is "A DataTable named 'Table1' already belongs to this DataSet."

Comment: this is weird, it still does not work with diff datatable names.